# Proving that this set of linear maps is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

How should I go about solving this problem. Any help will do, I just don't know where to start. Thanks in advance. 
Show that the subset of linear maps *L*: $\Bbb R^3$ $\to$ $\Bbb R^2$ defined by 
*S*=$\{L: \Bbb R^3$ $\to$ $\Bbb R^2$ : *L*(1, 2, 3)=0,   (2, 3)=*L*(x) for some x $\in$  $\Bbb R^3$ $\}$ 
is not a subspace of Hom($\Bbb R^3$, $\Bbb R^2$)

Comment: Do you understand that  title of the your question does not make any sense?

Comment: Sorry bout that. I did not catch that when I posted the question, thanks for telling me.

Comment: A subspace always has the zero element, in this case the zero element of $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the zero homomorphism. Now can you see that $S$ does not contain the zero homomorphism？

Comment: I fixed the title for you.